# sort.Reverse in Go

Tags: sorting, go, interface

I'm looking at the `sort.Reverse` code:

```
type reverse struct {
    // This embedded Interface permits Reverse to use the methods of
    // another Interface implementation.
    Interface
}

// Less returns the opposite of the embedded implementation's Less method.
func (r reverse) Less(i, j int) bool {
    return r.Interface.Less(j, i)
}

// Reverse returns the reverse order for data.
func Reverse(data Interface) Interface {
    return &reverse{data}
}
```

As far as I understand `reverse` implements `Interface` (and overrides `Less`) and `*reverse` does not implement `Interface`. Why does `Reverse` return `*reverse` (which somehow is `Interface`)?

Comment: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets: "The method set of the corresponding pointer type *T is the set of all methods declared with receiver *T or T (that is, it also contains the method set of T)." So *reverse has also the methods of reverse.

Comment: Aha, I got it. I thought that *T and T always have non-overlapping method sets. If you expand this comment to an answer I will accept it. Thanks!

Comment: @Marii no *T and T are different types of receivers. you cannot pass two methods with same name having T or *T type. It will show an error. Please check this link https://play.golang.org/p/VxRtiPhslun

Comment: This is a very good question. I hope there will be more upvotes. For a complete answer I recommend the chapter about embedding from effective go: https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding

Answer (score -1):

For your comment:

> As far as I understand reverse implements Interface (and overrides
>   Less)

There is no method overriding in Golang. It is not overriding `Less`. It is implementing `Less` of `Interface` which is an `interface` type:

```
type Interface interface {
        // Len is the number of elements in the collection.
        Len() int
        // Less reports whether the element with
        // index i should sort before the element with index j.
        Less(i, j int) bool
        // Swap swaps the elements with indexes i and j.
        Swap(i, j int)
}
```

For the question asked:

> Why does Reverse return *reverse (which somehow is Interface)

Because to change the order of the data it should be an address of the reverse struct. That's why it is `*reverse`. Now you can pass any type implementing `Interface` interface. And for implementing the `Interface` you should implement all the methods defined inside `Interface`.

```
type IntSlice []int

func (p IntSlice) Len() int           { return len(p) }
func (p IntSlice) Less(i, j int) bool { return p[i] < p[j] }
func (p IntSlice) Swap(i, j int)      { p[i], p[j] = p[j], p[i] }
```

In above case you can see that `IntSlice` implements the `Interface`. Hence you can pass the `Intslice` as an argument to Reverse.

As an example you can also implement using `Float` values as:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

func main() {
    //s := []int{5, 2, 6, 3, 1, 4} // unsorted
    s1 := []float64{5.2, 2.6, .6, .03, 2.1 } // unsorted
    sort.Sort(sort.Reverse(sort.Float64Slice(s1)))
    fmt.Println(s1)
}
```

[Playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/JDd8GJ2GWLQ)